# Получение regexp через ajax

Tags: php, ajax, регулярные-выражения

у меня есть файл на сервере vajx.php содержащий переменные:

```
$PRO_REGULAR['name']['preg'] = '/^[а-яА-Я]{3}|[a-zA-Z]{3}$/';
$P_REGULAR['email']['preg'] = '/^((([0-9A-Za-z]{1}[-0-9A-z\.]{1,}[0-9A-Za-z]{1})|([0-9А-Яа-я]{1}[-0-9А-я\.]{1,}[0-9А-Яа-я]{1}))@([-A-Za-z]{1,}\.){1,2}[-A-Za-z]{2,})$/u';

if (isset($_REQUEST)) {
    if ($_GET['id'] == 'getpreg') {
    echo json_encode($P_REGULAR[$_GET['key']]);
    }   
}
```

и есть скрипт который делает запрос в этот файл

```
function getregular (v,k) {
$.ajax({
        url: 'vajx.php?id=getpreg&key='+k,
        method: "POST",
        success: function(e) {
            var ans = JSON.parse(e);
            
            if ((v.search(ang))+1) {
            console.log('yes');     
            } else {
            console.log('no');
            }
        }
    });
}

 getregular ('dantelol','name');
```

но по какой то причинет - регулярное выражение получается скриптом не как регулярно, а по моему как просто строка - в общем формат данных как я понял не тот, и search() или test() возвращают -1 - отсутствие совпаденией (или как в моем случае 0 - так как я к результату прибавляю 1)

подскажите как правильно получать такого рода данные через ajax

Comment: console.log(e) ???

Comment: `new RegExp(ans)`?

Comment: `if (new RegExp(ans).test(v))`?

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю смысла запрашивать регулярку с сервера, чтобы потом по ней проверять на клиенте. Вы можете сразу проверить на сервере данные, а клиенту выдавать true|false. Или же регулярку хранить на клиенте и проверять на клиенте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если с сервера через JSON приходит строка типа `'/[re]/'`, тогда придется использовать `eval('/re/')`. Если же вы можете настроить сервер, чтобы с него приходила строка с чистым кодом регулярки, без обрамляющих слешей (т.е. `'[re]'`), тогда можно использовать `RegExp('[re]')` или `RegExp('[re]', 'u')` с нужным флагом. Только позаботьтесь о нужном экранировании слешей. Если у вас регулярка `/\w/`, то в строке нужно передавать `'\\w'`.